# pandas to_sql() and read_sql_query() dealing with empty string

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a df with string type column, and the cell might be empty string ""(no space in between). I want to write the df into mysql like the following:

```py
df.to_sql(name, conn)
```

and then I want to query the df and filter out the cells with empty string like:

```py
sql = 'select * from <tabname> where col = "" '
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
```

however, it will throw errors:
(pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'by = "" and ds = 20190618\' at line 1')
I have tried to use like:

```
sql = "select * from <tabname> where col = '' "
<or>
sql = 'select * from <tabname> where col = \'\'' . 
<or> 
sql = 'select * from <tabname> where col = {0}'.format('')
```

but neither worked:
(pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'by = ''  and ds = 20190618' at line 1")
the error message showed that **it successfully parsed the sql query string** but it seemed mysql didn't recognize it.

Comment: try `"select * from <tabname> where col = ' ' "` worked for me.

Comment: @Datanovice,thanks but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can go about it like this:

```
sql = 'select * from <tabname> where col = \'\' '
```

As your connection seems to expect single quoted text you can escape the single quotes and use them inside string.